# How to send typeof json instead json string

Tags: json, ajax, laravel-5.7

Sending response as json from laravel function It is sending as json but when receive in ajax success, it is not real json object but string like below

```
{"hotel_country":"Taiwan","hotel_city":"Taipei"}
```

I want to perform this check

```
 if (response && response.indexOf("application/json") !== -1)
```

I know I can do `JSON.parse(response)` but if there is solution of just receive real time json object in js that would be great.

**Laravel**

```
$resData['success'] = true;
$resData['message'] = "Hotel was created successfully!";

$response = Response::json($data);
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

**Ajax**

```
function ajax_function(form){
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      url: form.action,
      type: form.method,
      data: {"data":formData},
      headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response) {
        // if (response && response.indexOf("application/json") !== -1)
        var jsonrules = JSON.parse(response);

        if(jsonrules.success == true)
        {

          document.getElementById(formId).reset();

          $('.is-valid').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('is-valid');
          });


          $("#submit_success_msg_div").fadeIn().html('<i id="submit_success_msg_icon" class="icon fas fa-check"></i>'+jsonrules.message);
          setTimeout(function(){ 
            $("#submit_success_msg_div").fadeOut();
          }, 3000);

        }else if(jsonrules.success == false)
        {
          $("#submit_fail_msg_div").fadeIn().html('<i id="submit_fail_msg_icon" class="fas fa-times"></i> Sorry hotel was not created');
          setTimeout(function(){
            $("#submit_fail_msg_div").fadeOut();
          }, 3000);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "json object". JSON **always** is a string. You can parse it, then the result is an object. But that object is not JSON anymore.

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: Depending on how you have set up the client side, parsing happens automatically. For example, when jQuery sees an `application/json` response content-type, it will parse the JSON for you. In other configurations you might have to call `JSON.parse()` yourself, but `JSON.parse()` needs to be called either way.

Comment: how can I use automatically parsed json in my ajax success response

Comment: As I said, this depends on how your client side is set up.

Comment: Please can you show your ajax code.